Cover all 1 pixels in a 0-1 image with minimum number of fixed size square
Problem Definition
For a 0-1 image in pixel shape of MxN and a given integer A, a feasible solution of the problem is defined as a certain number of AxA shape of pixel squares whose union may cover all of the 1-pixels in MxN image, in which the edges of the squares are parallel to edge of MxN image and aligned to pixels.
For all of the feasible solutions, I need to find any one of it who contains minimum number of squares.
What I want to ask is, is there any algorithm that may solve such problem or similar problems? Or, any suggestions about the region(Computer Vision? or Discrete Optimization?) I can seek for the algorithm I want?
Example of feasible solution
Problem Set

M = N = 25, A = 15
The to-be-covered area is colored with grey in the image below


Feasible Solution

Three squares covering part of the area, colored with higher saturation.

And the union of the squares, covering all of the grey pixels

So the three squares make up a feasible solution of the problem, and actually its also one of the optimal solution.

Other Information

The to-be-cover area is almost definite to be not convex, but connected.
Actually I don't need a policy to find the mathematical optimal solution. I'd prefer a policy that may find a good enough, almost feasible solution in limited time/complexity.


I have no idea what your question means. And you appear to have posted the solution to a problem you don't appear to have shared - where's your input image please?

It looks like A is 16, not 15. Also, what is the question? What is the problem you encountered when trying? Code?

Sorry for the confusing image in the example, I've rectified the image and added more specific descriptions. @MarkSetchell

@trincot And I'm posting this problem to ask for suggestions about possible algorithms to solve it or regions which I may seek for the algorithm. I really have no idea about what kind of problem it is. Is it a classic problem in CV or Computer Graphics? Or should I try something about optimization, e.g. dynamic programming?

Well, it can be written as a kind of dominating set problem, which are usually hard. I found a paper about the rectangle case and a question that seems related. Both point at NP completeness. There should be a bunch of approximate algos (first paper describes one), but you're better off looking for them in papers according to proper terminology than asking here.

@Xellos Great thanks. I used to think it's just a simple or common question which involves a well-known algorithm, and didn't expect it to be so complex that reaches academic field.
